# Flutter load json in ListView return always empty data

Tags: android, json, flutter

I' m trying to build a simple app for viewing json data.
I started with the example on flutter website: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

This is working.

Now I' m trying to load a List of comments from: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/

When I run the app I see only the circle loaded from CircularProgressIndicator. Why? I'm not able to get the data but I don' t understand why, can you help me? Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter json test',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter json test'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Future<List<Comment>> _getComments() async {

    var data = await http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/");
    List<Comment> comments = [];

    if(data.statusCode==200) {
      var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

      for (var d in jsonData) {
        Comment comment = Comment(
            d["postId"],d["id"], d["name"], d["email"], d["body"]);

        comments.add(comment);
      }

      print(comments.length.toString());

      return comments;
    }
    else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getComments(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text( snapshot.data[index]['name']),
                    subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index]['email']),
                    onTap: (){
                      Navigator.push(context,
                          new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage(snapshot.data[index]))
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {

  final Comment comment;

  DetailPage(this.comment);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(comment.name),
        )
    );
  }
}


class Comment {
  final int postId;
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String body;

  Comment(this.postId, this.id, this.name, this.email, this.body);

}
```

Can you give me any advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to convert your JSON data into `Map<String, dynamic>` and then parsed it into `List`. By looking at your `code` you have only converted data into List so the `Type int is not a subtype of String error occurred`. Also, you have not added an error statement into your FutureBuilder so you have to face difficulties to read error so please do check my answer

You need to call this `CommentPage` from your `main.dart` file

```
class CommentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _homePage();
  }
}

class _homePage extends State<CommentPage> {
  Future<List<CommentModel>> getPostData() async {
    var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments";
    final responce = await http.get(url);
    final parsed = json.decode(responce.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<CommentModel>((json) {
      return CommentModel.fromJson(json);
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<CommentModel>>(
          future: getPostData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
                      subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].email));
                },
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
              );
            }
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my `model` class. I created this by using [this](https://quicktype.io/) online tool.

```
class CommentModel {
  CommentModel({
    this.postId,
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.body,
  });

  int postId;
  int id;
  String name;
  String email;
  String body;

  factory CommentModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CommentModel(
    postId: json["postId"],
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    email: json["email"],
    body: json["body"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "postId": postId,
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "email": email,
    "body": body,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `Comment` instances not `Map` instances so you should use the dot accessor. I'm sure if you check your console, you might see the error.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text( snapshot.data[index].name), // Change here
      subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].email), // Change here
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(context,
         new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
            DetailPage(snapshot.data[index]))
         );
      },
    );
  }
)
```